# On a special type of Noetherian regular rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module, global-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring having the property that for every $R$-module $M$ that has finite projective dimension, every submodule of $M$ also has finite projective dimension. Then $R$ is obviously regular since every ideal has finite projective dimension.

My question is: Does $R$ have finite global dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If $R$ has infinite global dimension, then it has a module $X$ of infinite projective dimension. But if $P_0\to X$ is a surjective map from a projective module to $X$, with kernel $Y$, then $Y$ must have infinite projective dimension, since if $Y$ had a finite projective resoltion
$$\cdots\to 0\to P_n\to\cdots\to P_2\to P_1\to Y\to0$$
then $X$ would have a finite projective resolution
$$\cdots\to 0\to P_n\to\cdots \to P_1\to P_0\to X\to0.$$

So $Y$ is a module of infinite projective dimension that is a submodule of $P_0$, which is projective and so certainly has finite projective dimension.